# Foursquare hour venue API from after midnight adds +00 to hour

Tags: foursquare

I am using foursquare venue API for fetching the hours. And as the documentation  saids that it will return hours json representation as

> end   The time as HHMM (24hr) at which the segment ends. From https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/hours

I begin to see some places that close after midnight and returns the hour in a format with a plus sign like this.

```
open: [
{
start: "1100"
end: "+0200"
}
]
```

Does anyone know what that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  start: "1100"
  end: "+0200"
}
```

means: open 11:00 am - 2:00 am (next day)